# Button Click Event to Update TextView in Android Studio. Builds with no errors, but does not work

Tags: java, android, android-button

Resolved: The issue was with the java not running, not with the code itself. Fixed that and the button worked.

My button does (seemingly) nothing when I push it in the emulator.  I'm attempting to have text update when a button is pushed. I started off by reading the [Android Dev Button Guide](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button), and other answered questions, but even when directly copy-pasting the code voted as the correct answer from numerous questions, and updating with the names of my items, I still can't get it working.

This is the current java code:

```
public class PlusMinus extends Activity {

TextView mcvalue;
Button sub;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    mcvalue= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mcvalue);
    sub= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub5MC);

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View paramView) {
            mcvalue.setText("Click");
        }
    });

}}
```

This is the corresponding .xml for the text I want to update, and the button. There is more .xml surround it relating to the table layout I used, but I don't think that is relevant (if it is I can add the whole thing in).

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSub5MC"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:keepScreenOn="false"
            android:text="@string/subtract_five"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFD700"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/mcvalue"
            android:text="@string/megacredits_name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I want to replace the text of @string/megacredits_name displayed as "MC" with "Click." Eventually my plan is to do some adding/subtracting with it, but trying to figure out the simplest building block first before expanding on it.

Thank you

Edit: LogCat removed as it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Resolved: Used a toast to determine that nothing in the PlusMinus class was actually running and resolved it by fixing that issue.

Answer (score 1):

change **android:layout_width="0dp"**   to **android:layout_width="wrap_content"** of TextView and Button. 
and then ID to the TextView i.e. **android:id="@+id/mcvalue"**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mcvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFD700"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/megacredits_name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not help the button work. Is there a connection between the layout_width and the click being able to find the button?

Comment: set id to the text view

Comment: I clicked run, then logcat at the bottom of the screen, then pasted above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: and first you make TEXTVIEW layout_width="0dp" to wrap_content

Comment: I think that's the issue, I am not receiving any error, but when I click the button, bSub5MC, nothing happens anywhere that I can see.

Granted I am very new to this, so it could very well just be my misunderstanding of the tool. Thank you.

Edit to add: I expect that when I click the bSub5MC button, that the TextView with id MCValue would change to be "Click"

Comment: if its works...then please tick to the correct answer, located at up and down arrow

Answer (score 1):

in Layout file put layout_weight:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub5MC"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:keepScreenOn="false"
    android:text="click"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFD700"
    android:id="@+id/mcvalue"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in java file:

```
  TextView mcvalue;
    Button sub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.item_check);

        mcvalue= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mcvalue);
        sub= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub5MC);

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mcvalue.setText("click");
            }
        });
}
```